# Grails deployment to tomcat, only some links working

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, tomcat6

I've deployed my application to an ubuntu server running tomcat6. I did the deployment via a WAR file, and I've renamed it to ROOT.  When I go to the base url, I get a 404 error saying cannot find 'index.jsp'.  I found on the grails FAQ site, that this means it already tried to find a gsp but wasn't able to find it--however, I've verified in the extracted war that it does, indeed exist.

My default settings point to a HomeController which calls `index()` and there *is* a corresponing `/home/index.gsp` in the views folder under the extracted WAR.

Now to add some further confusion, I have another controller `ContactController` and the same view setup (i.e Contact/index.gsp) and *that* one will work! In fact, out of the 5 controllers I have, it's the only one that can find the view apparently, even though each view is named `index.gsp` in their own respective view folders.

I'm not sure that it's related to the app itself since it works using the run-app (although I certainly won't rule it out).  My guess is it's server related, but all the docs say a simple drop of the WAR in the `/webapps/` directory and restart.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller:"home", action:"index")
        "500" (view: '/error')
    }
}
```

The error exactly:

> The requested resource (/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/home/index.jsp) is
>   not available

Comment: Can you post your UrlMappings.groovy file?

Comment: I've added it to the question.  My Controller is named 'HomeController' not 'homeController'. Does that matter?

Comment: That all looks right to me. Lower case is what should be used when referring to controllers. Can you go directly to `/appName/home/index`?  Next can you add your `index` action from the `home` controller?

Comment: @Kelly I've put in the action too. I get the error: 'The requested resource (/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/home/index.jsp) is not available.' still

Comment: I don't see the `index` controller action in the question.  Could there be something you are doing in the individual `index.gsp` files that is keeping them from compiling?

Comment: @Kelly I've update the question to reflect the new mappings. The index.gsp's work with the run-app command locally. If that works, my assumption would be that they compile--safe?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13825/discussion-between-onresolve-and-kelly)

Answer (score 4):

We had this issue recently. Make sure that your controller is in the right package that corresponds to the directory structure.

For example:

```
package com.mypackage

class HomeController {
   def index = {
   }
}
```

is in **./grails-app/controllers/com/mypackage**.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you name the action as well as the controller in your root mapping?

```
"/"(controller:"home", action:"index")
```

Comment: Nope :( also, remember that the home one is not the only one that doesn't load, just one particular controller + view works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ' allowLinking="true" ' attribute to the Context tag in the context.xml file

you can see that context.xml file in ${TOMCAT_HOME}\conf folder